# Replace div contents with jQuery on form submit within PHP loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, while-loop, replacewith

I have this jQuery form being outputted in a PHP while loop if the button has not previously been clicked and just an image with the value if it has, the function is like facebooks like button where when the user clicks the button the icon changes so its not clickable any longer and the value increments by 1. The form submission works but I cannot seem to update the icon image and value count in the feed without effecting all the other buttons and values in the feed… I tried jQuery `replaceWith()` but it replaces all the `#bumpCont` divs in the feed…

index.php

```
<div class="images">
<?php
while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
    $path = $row['path'];
    $user = $row['user'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    $desc = $row['desc'];
    $update = $row['update_date'];
    $bump = $row['bump'];
    $timeFirst  = strtotime($date);
    $timeSecond = strtotime($update);
    $timeSecond = $timeSecond + 86400;
    $timer = $timeSecond - $timeFirst;

?>
<?php if(empty($desc)){}else{?><div id="desc"><?php echo $desc;?></div><?php }?>
<img id="pic" src="uploads/<?php echo $path;?>"/>
<div id="userCont">
<div id="user"><a rel="external" href="user_profile.php?user='.$user.'"><?php echo $user;?></a></div>
<div id="timer"><?php echo $timer;?></div>


<?php
if(in_array($path, $mypath)) {
    echo '<div id="bumpCont"><img id="bump" style="height:55px;right:8px;top: 2px;position: relative;" src="../img/bumpg.png"/><span id="bumpCount">'.$bump.'</span></div>';
}else{
    echo '<form method="post" id="bumpF" data-ajax="false">';
    echo '<input name="id" data-ajax="false" id="field_'.$id.'" type="hidden" value="'.$id.'" />';
    echo '<div id="bumpCont"><input type="image" style="height:55px;right:8px;top: 2px;position: relative; " id="bump" src="../img/bump.png" id="searchForm" onclick="SubmitForm('.$id.');" value="Send" /><span id="bumpCount">'.$bump.'</span></div>';
    echo ' </form>';
 }
?>

</div>

<?php
}
?>

//Submit Form
function SubmitForm(id) {
event.preventDefault();
var name = $('#field_'+id).val();
console.log(name);
$.post("bump.php", {name: name},
function(data) {
$( "#bumpCont" ).replaceWith( '<div id="bumpCont"><img id="bump" style="height:55px;right:8px;top: 2px;position: relative;" src="../img/bumpg.png"/><span id="bumpCount">' + data + '</span></div>' );
}
```

Bump.php -

```
$id =  $_POST['name'];
$sessionUser = $_SESSION['userSession'];

// GET USERNAME
$sql = "SELECT * FROM userbase WHERE user_id='$sessionUser'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $myname = $row['username'];
   }

}


$bump = 1;              
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id=$id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $bump = $row['bump'];
      $path = $row['path'];
      $desc = $row['desc'];
      $post_user = $row['user'];
        $bump++;
    }

}

$bumpC = 0;                 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bumped WHERE path='$path' AND myname ='$myname'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $bumpC++;
    }

}

echo $bump;

if($bumpC >= 1){

}else{
$sql = "INSERT INTO `bumped` ( `myname`,`path`, `description`, `post_user`) VALUES ( '$myname','$path', '$desc', '$post_user')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$sql = "UPDATE images SET update_date='$date' WHERE id=$id";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$sql = "UPDATE images SET bump=$bump WHERE id=$id";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem ?

Comment: Where is your code of having replaceWith() ?

Comment: Sure I want the span id of #bumpCount to update with the new value after being submitted to bump.php which is the echo $bump. I would like the whole bumpCont div to be reloaded to reflect the button being clicked so the image changes to reflect the click as well.. without reloading the page of course :-) I removed the replaceWith() as it didnt work so I am open different methods but I will put it back in to show my example..

Comment: I understand that you've multiple elements in loop and based on the click of particular element, you wanna change the contents of that particular element only, I've shown you an example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First look shows me a problem of `Elements with same ID in loop`.

You could have same class to multiple elements.

```
<div class="bumpCont"><span class="bumpCount">1</span></div>
<div class="bumpCont"><span class="bumpCount">2</span></div>
```

Use `$(this)`

Based on the click on particular element, you can change contents.

```
$('.bumpCount').click(function(){
  $(this).html(parseInt($(this).html) + 1);
});
```

Hope this helps you.

```js
$('.bumpCount').click(function(){
  $(this).html(parseInt($(this).html()) + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bumpCont"><span class="bumpCount">1</span></div>
<div class="bumpCont"><span class="bumpCount">2</span></div>
```

Comment: Yep that did it I just had to add the class to bumpCont with the id of the post and now im good.. Thanks a million! Cheers

Comment: @RyanD Glad to see that it works for you :) All the best